# ember.js apply object after setting new value for it's attribute

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Cheers!
Simple action here I have:

```
TravelClient.TourSeatsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectSeat: function(seat) {
    // console.log(seat.get('id'));
    // console.log(seat.get('free'));
    seat.set('free', false);
    TravelClient.Seat.apply(seat);
    // console.log(seat.get('free'));
  }
});
```

my html:

```
      {{#each seat in controller.seatsArray}}
        <li class="item">
          {{#if seat.free}}
            <div class="counter-value">
              <a href="#" {{action "selectSeat" seat}}>{{seat.id}}</a>
            </div>
...............................................................................
```

Object's structure:

```
  ...addObject(TravelClient.Seat.create({
    id: i,
    free: true
  }));
```

Set method works well, but when I trying to apply object with new setted property, Ember gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: __ember1360328485839
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `TravelClient.Seat.apply(seat);`?

Comment: hm, okay, so... then the question is - ho to save updated object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a transaction, add the seat to the transaction, modify the seat, then commit the transaction.

```
TravelClient.TourSeatsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectSeat: function(seat) {
    var transaction = new App.store.transaction();
    transaction.add(seat);
    seat.set('free', false);
    transaction.commit();
  }
});
```

Comment: It gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined`. I don't use ember-data in my app.

Comment: Oh, I undestood, I need ember-data store or it;s workaround analog for this, so dummy I am.