# Ember.js saving updated object without ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my app I don't use ember-data, so how I can save an object with updated attribute?
I use `.set()` to change object's attribute, but how to do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a complete question in any possible sense.  Assuming you are trying to save a model to a persistence layer, you will need to send an XHR to your server with the model's fields serialized.  Your server will then need to return a response that you parse in the XHR's callback that you use to update your model on the client-side.

If you want a more detailed answer you must ask a more detailed question.

Comment: Sorry for duplicating, look this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773426/ember-js-apply-object-after-setting-new-value-for-its-attribute
and I'm going to delete this question with some delay, thank you.